# Errors converting Character to Numeric R

Tags: r, dataframe, mean, numeric

I want to make a character column to numeric, so I can calculate the mean of basepay. However I keep getting different errors.

I use the code

```
dataset <- read.csv("Wagegap.csv")

SFWage <- dataset %>% 
  as.numeric(dataset$BasePay)%>%
  group_by(gender,JobTitle, Year) %>%
  summarise(averageBasePay = mean(BasePay, na.rm=TRUE)) %>%
              select(gender, JobTitle, averageBasePay, Year)

clean <- SFWage %>% filter(gender != "")
```

It either wont recognize my basepay column if i don't use $, and if i use $ it shows

> Error in function_list[i] :
> 'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

The basepay column shows numbers with a "." instead of "," so I don't have to use a gsub()?

Comment: please show what the dataframe looks like. I think it should be ```mutate(BasePay = as.numeric(BasePay))```

Comment: SFWage <- dataset %>% 
      as.numeric(dataset$BasePay)%>%

Here you are passing your dataset, which is a dataframe, as the first argument to the as.numeric() function. as.numeric doesn't work with entire dataframe. You can use @StupidWolf's code.

Comment: thank you for the fast comments it works by using dataset$BasePay <- as.numeric(dataset$BasePay) before the piping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this before all the piping :

```
dataset$BasePay <- as.numeric(dataset$BasePay)
```